# Create a RVM gemset in a shared host environment

Tags: rubygems, rvm, shared-hosting

Anyone know if there is a configuration variable to tell rvm to create the gemset in my home directory (no root access)?

```
[p3r66567@cp40 (ruby-1.8.6) ~]$ type rvm | head -1
rvm is a function

[p3r66567@cp40 (ruby-1.8.6) ~]$ which rvm
/usr/local/rvm/bin/rvm

[p3r66567@cp40 (ruby-1.8.6) ~]$ rvm gemset create testgemset
mkdir: cannot create directory `/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.6-p399@testgemset': Permission denied

info: Gemset 'testgemset' created.
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this line:

```
export rvm_gems_path="$HOME/.rvm/gems"
```

to ~/.rvmrc

Comment: I'm no expert, but I can't find anything in the rvm docs that would allow a sysadmin to specifically prohibit them.  What errors are you seeing?

Answer (score 1):

If you installed rvm with root for a multiuser session, and now you are logged in with a different user, make sure that user belongs to the rvm group. If not run this from your root session:

> usermod -a -G rvm youruser

Ger